# Selecting rows with multi-index columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with multi-indexed columns, like this:

```py
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['one', '', '', 'two', 'two', 'two'],
                                ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']])
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 6), columns=col)
data
```

[image]

I want to be able to select all rows where the values in one of the level 1 columns pass a certain test. If there were no multi-index on the columns I would say something like:

```
data[data['d']<1]
```

But of course that fails on a multindex. The level 1 indexes are unique, so I don't want to have to specify the level 0 index, just level 1. I'd like to return the table above but missing row 1, where d>1.

Comment: Your example dataframe code differs from your screenshot.

Comment: the screenshot is of what the code produces in Jupyter

Answer (score 3):

If values are unique in second level id necessary convert mask from one column DataFrame to `Series` - possible solution with [`DataFrame.squeeze`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html):

```
np.random.seed(2019)
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['one', '', '', 'two', 'two', 'two'],
                                ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']])
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 6), columns=col)


print (data.xs('d', axis=1, level=1))
        two
0  1.331864
1  0.953490
2 -0.189313
3  0.064969

print (data.xs('d', axis=1, level=1).squeeze())
0    1.331864
1    0.953490
2   -0.189313
3    0.064969
Name: two, dtype: float64

print (data.xs('d', axis=1, level=1).squeeze().lt(1))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
Name: two, dtype: bool

df = data[data.xs('d', axis=1, level=1).squeeze().lt(1)]
```

Alternative with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = data[data.xs('d', axis=1, level=1).iloc[:, 0].lt(1)]
```

---

```
print (df)
        one                           two                    
          a         b         c         d         e         f
1  0.573761  0.287728 -0.235634  0.953490 -1.689625 -0.344943
2  0.016905 -0.514984  0.244509 -0.189313  2.672172  0.464802
3  0.845930 -0.503542 -0.963336  0.064969 -3.205040  1.054969
```

---

If working with `MultiIndex` after select is possible get multiple columns, like here if select by `c` level:

```
np.random.seed(2019)
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['one', '', '', 'two', 'two', 'two'],
                                ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']])
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 6), columns=col)
```

So first select by [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) and compare by [`DataFrame.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) for `<`

```
print (data.xs('c', axis=1, level=1))
                  two
0  1.481278  0.685609
1 -0.235634 -0.344943
2  0.244509  0.464802
3 -0.963336  1.054969

m = data.xs('c', axis=1, level=1).lt(1)
#alternative
#m = data.xs('c', axis=1, level=1) < 1
print (m)
            two
0  False   True
1   True   True
2   True   True
3   True  False
```

And then test if at least one `True` per rows by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = data[m.any(axis=1)]
print (df1)
        one                           two                    
          a         b         c         a         b         c
0 -0.217679  0.821455  1.481278  1.331864 -0.361865  0.685609
1  0.573761  0.287728 -0.235634  0.953490 -1.689625 -0.344943
2  0.016905 -0.514984  0.244509 -0.189313  2.672172  0.464802
3  0.845930 -0.503542 -0.963336  0.064969 -3.205040  1.054969
```

Or test if all `True`s per row by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) with filtering:

```
df1 = data[m.all(axis=1)]
print (df1)
        one                           two                    
          a         b         c         a         b         c
1  0.573761  0.287728 -0.235634  0.953490 -1.689625 -0.344943
2  0.016905 -0.514984  0.244509 -0.189313  2.672172  0.464802
```

Answer (score 2):

Using your supplied data, a combination of [xs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html#pandas.DataFrame.xs) and [squeeze](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) can help with the filtering. This works on the assumption that the level 1 entries are unique, as indicated in your question :

```
np.random.seed(2019)
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['one', '', '', 'two', 'two', 'two'],
                                ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']])
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 6), columns=col)
data

       one                                         two
         a          b         c            d            e          f
0   -0.217679   0.821455    1.481278    1.331864    -0.361865   0.685609
1   0.573761    0.287728    -0.235634   0.953490    -1.689625   -0.344943
2   0.016905    -0.514984   0.244509    -0.189313   2.672172    0.464802
3   0.845930    -0.503542   -0.963336   0.064969    -3.205040   1.054969
```

Say you want to filter for d less than 1 :

```
#squeeze turns it into a series, making it easy to pass to loc via boolean indexing
condition = data.xs('d',axis=1,level=1).lt(1).squeeze()
#or you could use loc : 
# condition = data.loc(axis=1)[:,'d'].lt(1).squeeze()

data.loc[condition]

        one                                              two
       a             b           c         d            e           f
1   0.573761    0.287728    -0.235634   0.953490    -1.689625   -0.344943
2   0.016905    -0.514984   0.244509    -0.189313   2.672172    0.464802
3   0.845930    -0.503542   -0.963336   0.064969    -3.205040   1.054969
```

Comment: my bad. i just noticed u had squeeze in there. it wasnt in ur earlier answer

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done using `query`;

```
data.query("some_column <1")
```

and `get_level_values`

```
data[data.index.get_level_values('some_column') < 1]
```

Comment: did u try it out?

Comment: Hi. Yeah, I tried them.

     `data.query("some_column <1")`

produces the error

     `name 'd' is not defined`

while

     `data[data.index.get_level_values('some_column') < 1]`

produces the error

     `Requested level (d) does not match index name (None)`

Comment: I should have said:

`data.query("d <1")` produces the error `name 'd' is not defined` while `data[data.index.get_level_values('d') < 1]` produces the error `Requested level (d) does not match index name (None)`

Comment: Can you take a look at these docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/indexing.html#the-query-method-experimental

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help. As usual with these things, the specific answer to the problem is not as interesting as what you've learned in trying to fix it, and I learned a lot about `.query`, `.xs` and much more.

However, I ended up taking a side route to addressing my specific issue - namely that I copied the columns to a new variable, dropped an index, did my calculations, then put the original indexes in place. Eg:

```
cols = data.columns
data..droplevel(level=1, axis=1)
# do calculations
data.columns = cols
```

The advantage was that I could top and tail the operation modifying the indexes, but all the data manipulation in between used idioms I'm familiar with.

At some point I'll sit down and read about multi-indexes at length.